# How to save and exit "nano .bash_profile" in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, text-editor

I need to add some line to nano .bash_profile in Terminal. Then:

1) I enter with this command line: `nano .bash_profile`

2) Add the line I need

3) now I don't know how to Save and Exit

I thought it is **:w** + **enter**. If this is correct I need some direction to use it.

Comment: I'm using control+O to save..but it keep asking 'File Name to Write: .bash_profile So how to make sure the 'edited' .bash_profile file is saved?

Comment: Just press 'Enter' then

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, `:w` is a `/usr/bin/vi` command. Use the combination <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit. You will be prompted to save the file if you have made unsaved changes.

---

Nano is intended to be a bit friendlier / simpler to new users than vi/vim or emacs which both cater to more power users that have spent time learning how to use them effectively.

To get started in nano - look for commands along the bottom of the window when nano is open. (`^` stands for the <kbd>control</kbd> key)

```
^X      (F2)            Close the current file buffer / Exit from nano
^O      (F3)            Write the current file to disk
```

Comment: Keep in mind the `shift` key is needed for ^X and ^0 , tripped me up at first when we're used to being given commands in uppercase and the shift key explicitly stated as a shortcut in OSX.

Comment: what is ^ sign? Pressing Shift + 6 and then X to create ^X seems not working!
Got it, it seems ^ sign means Ctrl in linux world!

Comment: ctrl + ^ + O will do the trick for you.

Comment: @paranza ctrl and ⌃ is the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

Per [Apple's Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203213):

> 6. To save the file, press Control-O.
> 7. At the filename prompt, press Enter.
> 8. To exit, press Control-X.

Comment: Best answer. to the point

Answer (score 5):

If you want to save the changes you've made, press <kbd>Control</kbd>+ <kbd>O</kbd>. To exit nano, type <kbd>Control</kbd>+ <kbd>X</kbd>. If you ask nano to exit from a modified file, it will ask you if you want to save it. Just press **N** in case you don't, or **Y** in case you do. It will then ask you for a filename. Just type it in and press Enter.

If you accidentally confirmed that you want to save the file but you actually don't, you can always cancel by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>when you're prompted for a filename.

Answer (score 3):

I just have the same question.
after a lot of trail and error i learned that Nano is asking you to write the name of the "new conf file".
Since you do not want a new file just hit enter indicating to nano that you want to keep the same name.

Basically you change the conf file,  pres Ctrl + x  and finally hit Enter (to indicate the same name).
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter `nano .bash_profile` (It will open the `.bash_profile` file in
   the nano editor)
2. After making changes to the file use  <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> (to "exit")
3. Then it asks for the changes to be made permanently and gives two options:
   `Yes (or) No`
4. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file

Answer (score -1):

Hey I got something for you guys 
just enter ctrl + x
and when it says to save press 'Y' if you want to save
Then just press enter button 
Hope it works :)

Comment: How does this differ from the other four answers already describing the same solution?

Answer (score -6):

Try

> sudo nano .bash_profile

To open your file instead. This will create your file if it doesn't exist, or open it for editing.

Comment: This is not the right place to use `sudo` -- that runs `nano` as root. It doesn't even really answer the question which is how do you save changes and exit  nano. He already knows how to start nano.

Comment: I know that it runs it as root. I had the same problem and doing the above fixed my problem. The accepted answer or an hour of research didn't. 

So unless the OP says this doesn't answer his question, I would disagree that it doesn't.